# Wordpress custom CORS headers is not authorized

Tags: php, wordpress, cors

Hey so I have this error message when I try to access some data using Javascript fetch :

`x-faustwp-secret headers is not authorized`

```
let response = await fetch('https://mywebsite.com/?rest_route=/faustwp/v1/authorize', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-faustwp-secret': apiClientSecret,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        code
    }),
});
```

When I bypass CORS using an extension (such as this one for instance https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/ ) everything works perfectly

So I think for some reason my CORS headers are getting ignored, in my Wordpress `function.php` I added :

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * , x-faustwp-secret"); // also tried without the *
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action( 'send_headers', 'add_cors_http_header' );
```

I even tried to add the headers directly in .htaccess file using :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "* , x-faustwp-secret"
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know where it might come from or encountered this issue ? I contacted the support from my web server but they couldn't help.

Comment: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * , x-faustwp-secret")` doesn't make a lot of sense. It says "allow everything, and allow this one". The latter should be a subset of the former (unless you are using credentials, then `*` usually doesn't mean what people think it means).

Comment: When you use your browser's inspect tools, do you see the headers being send by the server?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I removed `x-faustwp-secret` from my header parameter like you suggested, ran the request again and checked the response
 `access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type`

Comment: If this is truly running in a WP REST context, you might be able to use [`rest_allowed_cors_headers`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_allowed_cors_headers/)

Comment: @ChrisHaas using `rest_allowed_cors_headers` worked ! Thank you very much

Comment: @ChrisHaas `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * , x-faustwp-secret` indeed doesn't make much sense but it's worth pointing out that it is [tolerated](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=POST&requestUseCORS=1&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&preflightAllowMethods=POST&preflightAllowHeaders=*%2C+x-faustwp-secret&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&requestHeaderName=x-faustwp-secret&requestHeaderValue=whatever&requestHeaderName=content-type&requestHeaderValue=whatever).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @ChrisHaas I found a solution using `rest_allowed_cors_headers`

```
function custom_rest_cors_headers( $headers ) {
    $headers[] = "*";
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'rest_allowed_cors_headers', 'custom_rest_cors_headers' );
```